# elements in C array strange change

Tags: arrays, c

my codes are here. when I print arr[4], sometimes the value is 0, but sometimes the value is 2, it's very strange

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int countBalls(int, int);

void main() {
    int res;
    res = countBalls(1, 10);
    printf("result：%d\n", res);
}

int countBalls(int lowLimit, int highLimit)
{
    int i;
    int num=0,max =0,maxNum=0;
    int arr[highLimit];
    memset(arr, 0, highLimit);
    printf("arr[4]:%d\n", arr[4]);
    for(i=lowLimit; i<=highLimit; i++) {
        printf("arr[4]:%d\n", arr[4]);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `memset(arr, 0, highLimit);` -> `memset(arr, 0, highLimit * sizeof(int));`, or `memset(arr, 0, highLimit * sizeof(*arr));`

Comment: `void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );`
value is converted to *unsigned char*. So, you are filling 10 bytes of 0s in the array.
Assuming you are on 32-bit machine and integer is 32-bit, 10 byte corresponds first, second integer element in array and first (or last, depending on the endiannes) 2 byte of the third element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not zeroing out the entire array.

```
memset(arr, 0, highLimit);
```

The third parameter to `memset` is the number of **bytes** to set, not the number of array elements.  Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes, this means you only zero out the first two elements and half of the third.

You need to multiply by the element size.

```
memset(arr, 0, highLimit * sizeof *arr);
```